# OpenCV LK Optical Flow Depth (Z)

Tags: c++, opencv, depth, opticalflow

Im calculating optical flow (OF) through the OpenCV calcOpticalFlowPyrLK function on points which i tracked before. This works as it should. Now i try to obtain the relative depth Z.

For this i tried to use following 2 equation for u and v:

```
     (Tz*x - Tx*f)           (Tz*y - Ty*f)
u =  ______________      v = _____________
            Z                     Z
```

I left out the rotation part of the equation because i assume that i have pure translation.
Solved both equations from above for Z and tried to compute Z with values (coordinates) i obtained from the previous OF caculation step.

- For the vars x,y i used the image coordinates from image1.
- For u and v i used the points i obtained from the OF calculation -> tracked points in image2.
- For example lets say x = 413, y = 210, u = 415, v = 210, Tx = -0.9, Ty = -0.176, Tz = -0.3846, f = 640

*My Problem is that i get 2 different Z values as a result. 
In my opinion the depth should be equal for both?*

I searched for some more infos on how i could solve my problem and found a good [paper](http://refbase.cvc.uab.es/files/NSH2013.pdf) except that i think they mixed Farnback and LK in their performance analyses. 
As far as i understand the math behind the equation (4, page 4) it is the same as the equation above, just in matrix representation. I tried it to solve aswell with the above values and i got a 2x2 matrix as result. Dont know what i should do with 4 Z values ?!

Hopefully someone can explain what im doing wrong and guide me in the right direction so that im able to get the correct Z value (depth) from OF. Thanks!